# Error in google mapview

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently doing an application which contains googlemap . The code of that xml file is given below , but in Graphical layout it shows an error

"Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme"

When running googlemap it shows the error in logcat as

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iqmobi/com.iqmobi.Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView

the xml and manifest files are given below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/layout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">



     <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
     android:id="@+id/myMapView1" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:clickable="true" 
     android:apiKey="0mRN-6bSm63hZJtPZSmcjoZAzdCztLnZv-O4SZw" 
     >
     </com.google.android.maps.MapView>  





    </LinearLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.iqmobi"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/iconffff"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.iqmobi.Map"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
       >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Clean your project and try to run. If no use for this, simply restart your workspace and try it out.

Comment: Have you extend map activity instead of activity ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Comment: The  error in graphical layout is remaining

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the main class as MapActivity

```
public class Abc extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Layout to RelativeLayout and remove this line `</com.google.android.maps.MapView>`
Put it like this, without layout id, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
          android:id="@+id/myMapView1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="api key" />

</RelativeLayout>
```